# $X\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ has measure zero iff $\forall x\in X$, $\exists U\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ open with $x\in U$ such that $U\cap X$ has measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to prove the following statement:

> $X\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ has measure zero iff $\forall x\in X$, $\exists U\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ open with $x\in U$ such that $U\cap X$ has measure zero.

I think I need second countability, but I am not sure how to use it.

I think the forward implication is trivial (just take $U=\mathbb{R}^n$). I am having trouble showing the reverse implication.

Comment: Which of the two directions of the "iff" equivalence is easier? Have you tried to do the easier direction at least?

Comment: I think the forward implication is trivial (just take $U=\mathbb{R}^n$), I am having trouble showing the reverse implication.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first direction, for any $x\in X$, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set with $X\cap\mathbb{R}^n\subseteq X$, which consequently has measure zero by monotonicity.

For the other direction, for each $x\in X$, let $U_x$ with $x\in U_x$ be open and such that $X\cap U_x$ has measure zero. Furthermore, for each $x\in X$, we can find a ball $B_{r_x}(q_x)$ with $r_x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,\infty)$ and $q_x\in\mathbb{Q}^n$ such that $x\in B_{r_x}(q_x)\subseteq U_x$. Then by monotonicity, $X\cap B_{r_x}(q_x)$ has measure zero, the collection $\mathscr{B}=\{B_{r_x}(q_x):x\in X\}$ is countable, and

$$X=\bigcup_{B\in\mathscr{B}}(X\cap B).$$

Consequently, using countable additivity, $X$ has measure zero.

Comment: What if $X\cap\Bbb Q^n=\varnothing?$

Comment: @AnneBauval ah you're right, not sure how I missed that. Anyways the argument should work with a slight modification; I'll write it up soon

Comment: @AnneBauval pretty sure it should work now

Answer (score 2):

You already commented that the forward implication is trivial.

For the converse, you were right to suggest using that $X$ is second countable. Let $(U_n)$ be a sequence of open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ such that $(U_n\cap X)$ is a basis for the induced topology on $X.$ By hypothesis and monotonicity, every $x\in X$ belongs to some $U_{n_x}$ such that $U_{n_x}\cap X$ has measure $0,$ hence so does $X=\bigcup_{n\in\{n_x\mid x\in X\}}\left(U_n\cap X\right).$